# chmod file with read permission but not delete , write and execute

Tags: permissions, chmod

I know i can set read , write and execute permission to a file with chmod but can i take away the permission to delete, write and execute?

Answer (score 0):

Removing is done by setting only the parts you want. For example, to remove write, and execute you would set the permission to `4` for that category of user. So to make only the owner have read, write, and execute and everyone else only read on a file you would use:

```
chmod 0744 ./target_file
```

Delete is done using write and execute **on the directory** that holds the file. In this example you could only allow the owner of the directory to delete files with:

```
chmod 0755 .
```

Comment: if a folder doest allow write can i still write inside a file if that file has the permission ?

Comment: Yes, the directory permissions will control the files that can be added or removed from the directory, but not if the file itself can change.

Answer (score 0):

The "delete" permission is not connected to the file. To delete a file, one requires "write" access to the file's parent directory.

Unsetting the write or execute permissions requires reading `man chmod`, but is easy.

Comment: if a folder doest allow write can i still write inside a file if that file has the permission ?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Write permission on a directory only controls the ability to create new files in that directory, or delete existing files from it.